# calculating 'expected' rainfall for a period (e.g., month) when there is zero-inflation and over dispersion

Tags: expected-value, descriptive-statistics, zero-inflation, overdispersion

I want to use 20 years of estimated precipitation data (maybe from CHELSA or CHIRPS datasets) to look at what the expected amount of precipitation is for different 30-day periods. The main purpose of this would be to identify month-long periods that are dryer than usual. If the rainfall data were normally distributed, I could use the mean and standard deviation. For example, one standard deviation below could be called 'lower rainfall' and one standard deviation above could be called 'higher rainfall'. But how would I deal with zero-inflation (say 15% of values are zero) and over dispersion (since rainfall has a lower bound of zero but no real upper bound). With such data, using mean and standard deviation would lead to a lot more cases of 'higher rainfall' periods than 'lower rainfall' periods because of how skewed the data would be. I imagine modelling rainfall could done with something like a zero-inflated gamma model, but I am very new to this. Any suggestions for calculating a range of expected precipitation for a period in order to see when values fall outside of this range?

Comment: You do not need a specific distribution, especially if you have a lot of data.  For example you could just call zero-rain months "no rain", other months in the lowest quartile "lower rainfall", months in the highest months "higher rainfall", and the remaining months (i.e. half of them) "close to typical".  Or something along similar lines.  Note that rainfall is seasonal in many places, so you might prefer to compare each month with the same month in different years - it all depends on what you want to show.

Comment: What should count as "lower than normal" (or higher) is not really a statistical question, its very application dependent. You *might* consider quantiles of the conditional  distribution (depending on the variables this model might be a function of; presumably at least time of year matters) of the response (not the fitted mean) or perhaps of the predictions, but *which* quantiles is again an application-dependent issue.

Comment: To clarify, I am not trying to calculate which months of the year are on average dryer. Instead, given how dry or wet a month typically is, what I want to know is whether the month in a given year is particularly dry or not.

Comment: The closest thing to a standard method for modelling precipitation with exact zeros is Tweedie distribution generalized linear models. Do a Google Scholar search for "precipitation Tweedie distribution" and you'll find a number of papers by Peter Dunn and other authors.

Comment: Hi, Gordon. Thank you for the suggestion. This looks promising and I am starting to delve into this literature. E.g., https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/joc.2162